# Microsoft Query; use of SubString in Excel

Tags: sql, database, excel

I'm trying to filter results from a Query i have created in Microsoft Query to pull data from a database into my Excel sheet.  Specifically I'm trying to filter out based on the nth character of a string.

I can easily filter out the based on the first char:

```
SOPOrderReturnLine.ItemCode Like 'A25%'
```

But I have no idea how I could filter to show only entries where the 10th char = "A".  I'm sure I have to use a Substring function, but it's not familiar to me and I'm struggling to get it to work.

Comment: What type of database are you using ?  It makes a difference...

Answer (score 1):

Try to edit your sql query and enter the following statement:

```sql
select * from SOPOrderReturnLine where substring(SOPOrderReturnLine.ItemCode,10,1) = 'A';
```

The statement should work for a MySql database as well as for an Sql Server in the background; (I've tested it with an MySql database).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In MSQuery (Jet under the covers, I think), the function is `Mid`.

```
SELECT * FROM tblLocation WHERE (Mid(LocationName,2,1)='e')
```

to find a lower case 'e' in the second location.

Answer (score 0):

I assume when you say MS Query, you are running a query against a DBMS (SQL Server or some other via ODBC).

The use of `substr`, `substring` or `mid` should work, depending on *which* DBMS.  That said, unless you're using MS Access, I think most DBMSs will support the underscore character as "any single character."  It might even work in Access, but I don't know for sure.  Therefore, I think in addition to the suggestions you've gotten, this will also work in most cases:

```
SOPOrderReturnLine.ItemCode Like '_________A%'
```

If you want to use substring, don't hold me to these, but I think:

Oracle / DB2 / SQLite - `substr`

Microsoft SQL Server / Sybase / MySQL - `substring`

MS Access - `mid`

PostgreSQL -`substr` or `substring`